# Eliminate duplicate columns in MySQL left join query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, left-join

I have two tables: 
question(id_question, name_question, text_question)
and choice(id_choice, text_choice, id_question)

my query in php code is :

```
$query =    ' SELECT q.name_question, q.text_question, c.text_choice'.
                        ' FROM question as q '.
                        ' LEFT JOIN choice as c ' .
                        ' ON q.id_question = c.id_question ' ;
```

When I check the result:

```
foreach ($db->loadObjectList() as $obj){

    echo $obj->name_question." ".$obj->text_question." ".$obj->text_choice."</br>";

}
```

What I get is :

```
Q1 Q1_text C1
Q1 Q1_text C2
Q1 Q1_text C3

Q2 Q2_text C4
Q2 Q2_text C5
```

What I want is :

```
Q1 Q1_text C1
           C2
           C3

Q2 Q2_text C4
           C5
```

So is there a way to do it in the SQL query ? And how to show the query result in PHP the way I want ?

Thank's for your help.

Comment: You essentially want to replace data columns with NULL. Usually SQL is not used for formatting but this is possible.

Comment: While problems of this nature *can* be solved in MySQL, typically I think it's better to handle issues of data display at the application level - in this case with a simple PHP loop. Generally, this then allows more flexibility in the design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved with two ways:

### **Using Only SQL:**

**SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19d46/14**

```
  SELECT case
       when c.text_choice = (select min(text_choice) from choice c2 where c2.id = q.id) then name_question
       else ""
       end as name_question,

       case
       when c.text_choice = (select min(text_choice) from choice c2 where c2.id = q.id) then text_question
       else ""
       end as  text_question,
       c.text_choice 

FROM question as q LEFT JOIN choice as c  
ON q.id = c.id
order by q.id, c.text_choice;
```

Result:

```
Q1  Q1_text C1
C2
C3
Q2  Q2_text C4
C5
C6
```

### Using PHP as well:

On initial viewing this can easily be accomplished via PHP and ordering your results by name_question.

```
$query =    ' SELECT q.name_question, q.text_question, c.text_choice'.
                        ' FROM question as q '.
                        ' LEFT JOIN choice as c ' .
                        ' ON q.id_question = c.id_question '  order by q.name_question;
```

When displaying the result:

```
$current_nameQuestion = "";    
foreach ($db->loadObjectList() as $obj){

        if($current_nameQuestion==$obj->name_question)
        {
           echo "       ".$obj->text_choice."</br>";
        }
        else
        {
           echo $obj->name_question." ".$obj->text_question." ".$obj->text_choice."</br>";
           $current_nameQuestion = $obj->name_question;
        }       
    }
```

The above PHP code, will only print the 2 column values when the `name_question` has not already been outputted.