# Database Query for multiple choice questions

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database, mysql-workbench

Hi I am Using MYSQL in which i have created a database Survey with tables

```
survey_categories(survey_id,survey_name) -- PK survey_id
survey_question(survey_id,question_id,question) -- PK question_id
survey_option(question_id,option_id,options) -- PK option_id
```

I want a query to fetch question once only with its options

```
 select q.question,o.options 
   from survey_question q, survey_options o, survey_categories s 
  where q.question_id=o.question_id 
     && s.survey_name='purchase' 
     && s.survey_id=q.survey_id
```

Can anyone recommend for the same?

Comment: what? the result in option repeating why not use group by option

Comment: no no question is repeating along with option say eg..q.your name,option-a,q.your name,option-b,q.your name,option-c,q.your name,option-d

Comment: edit your question and add the result and the things you want to achieve

Comment: Refere this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713439/eliminate-duplicate-columns-in-mysql-left-join-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have q.question,o.option fields then
You can try `

```
select distinct q.question_id,o.options _id,q.question,o.options from survey_question q, survey_options o, survey_categories s 
  where q.question_id=o.question_id 
     and s.survey_name='purchase' 
     and s.survey_id=q.survey_id
     group by q.question_id`
```

Using sub query-

```
select  o.question_id,o.options from  survey_options o where  o.question_id 
IN(select distinct q.question_id from survey_question q, survey_options o, survey_categories s 
  where q.question_id=o.question_id 
     and s.survey_name='purchase' 
     and s.survey_id=q.survey_id)
```

Comment: there is a field question in survey_question table

Comment: See i need only question not question_id and more over i need question along with its options ...only that much..

Comment: u can remove q.question_id from 'select' and use q.question in group by clause

Comment: also u can use sub query for this purpose

Comment: this query is giving me question_id with options and that too with question_id >=6